# Subsets of Finite Lebesgue measure sets

Tags: measure-theory

have a measure theory question that's got me stumped.

Let $A$ have finite, positive Lebesgue measure $p$. Show that for all $0<q<p$, there exists a subset $B$ of $A$ with measure $q$.

I know given epsilon we can find closed subsets whose difference in measure with the original set is less than epsilon, but that's about it.

Comment: Consider $A_r = \{ x\in A : \lVert x\rVert < r\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that the are in $\Bbb R$.

Let us consider 
$$f(x) = \int_A 1_{(-\infty,x)}d\lambda
$$
$f$ is increasing and
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+} f(x+h)-f(x) = \lim_{h\to 0^+}\int_A 1_{[x,x+h)}d\lambda = 0
$$
because of the Monotone convergence theorem, and also
$$\lim_{h\to 0^-} f(x+h)-f(x) = 0
$$
so $f$ is continuous; and as $f(x\to\infty)\to p$, the intermediate value theorem concludes.